# How to get Last 1 hour data, every 5 minutes, without grouping?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

How to trigger every 5 minutes and get data for the last 1 hour? I came up with this but it does not seem to give me all the rows in the last 1 hr. My reasoning is :

1. Read the stream,
2. filter data for last 1 hr based on timestamp column, and
3. write/print using `forEachbatch`. And
4. watermark it so that it does not hold on to all the past data.

   ```
    spark.
    readStream.format("delta").table("xxx")
      .withWatermark("ts", "60 minutes")
      .filter($"ts" > current_timestamp - expr("INTERVAL 60 minutes"))
    .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 minutes"))
      .foreachBatch{ (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>  batchDF.collect().foreach(println)
           }
    .start()
   ```

Or do I have to use a Window? But I can't seem to get rid of `GroupBy` if I use Window and I don't want to group.

```
spark.
  readStream.format("delta").table("xxx")
    .withWatermark("ts", "1 hour")
    .groupBy(window($"ts", "1 hour"))
    .count()
 .writeStream
    .format("console")
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 minutes"))
    .foreachBatch{ (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => 
         print("...entering foreachBatch...\n")
         batchDF.collect().foreach(println)
         }
 .start()
```

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of using spark streaming to execution your spark code every 5 minutes, you should use either an external scheduler (cron, etc...) or API [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) if you want to schedule processing in your code**

#### Why you shouldn't spark-streaming to schedule spark code execution

If you use spark-streaming to schedule code, you will have two issues.

First issue, spark-streaming processes data only once. So every 5 minutes, only the new records are loaded. You can think of bypassing this by using window function and retrieving aggregated list of rows by using [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#collect_list(columnName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), or an [user defined aggregate function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html), but then you will meet the second issue.

Second issue, although your treatment will be triggered every 5 minutes, function inside `foreachBatch` will be executed only if there are new records to process. Without new records during the 5 minutes interval between two execution, nothing happens.

In conclusion, spark streaming is not designed to schedule spark code to be executed at specific time interval.

#### Solution with java.util.Timer

So instead of using spark streaming, you should use a scheduler, either external such as [cron](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html), [oozie](https://oozie.apache.org/), [airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/), etc... or in your code

If you need to do it in your code, you can use [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) as below:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{current_timestamp, expr}
import spark.implicits._

val t = new java.util.Timer()
val task = new java.util.TimerTask {
  def run(): Unit = {
    spark.read.format("delta").table("xxx")
      .filter($"ts" > (current_timestamp() - expr("INTERVAL 60 minutes")))
      .collect()
      .foreach(println)
  }
}
t.schedule(task, 5*60*1000L, 5*60*1000L) // 5 minutes
task.run()
```